# OnlyOffice DocumentServer Spreadsheet Filter Consistency

Tags: onlyoffice

Problem, step by step:

1. Create a spreadsheet
2. Paste a csv file
3. Create a sort filter
4. Use the sort filter (A-Z)
5. Close the file (wait saving process)
6. Open the file (BANG: some rows was erased)

I consider a serious problem (consistency) as well as the correction a determining factor for an effective use or contracting of the solution.

This problem reproduced by me: https://youtu.be/M6_sEu8_F_E

Is there any expecting for repair or an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

This problem will fixed in version 4.2
See https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DocumentServer/issues/63#issuecomment-259364585 (I assume this is your issue too)